# sqlplus connection to Oracle 11g takes much more time to establish than from another machine

Tags: oracle-11g, connectivity

I have an existing Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit system that connects to Oracle 11g (11.2.0.4.0 64bit/Windows).

From that Linux machine I can connect to Oracle via sqlplus instantly, using `sqlplus uid/pwd@tnsname`

I just installed a Linux 18.04LTS, on which I installed the same oracle client and RPM header packages, prepared for 18.04 via `alien` package converter:

```
oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite 12.2.0.1.0-2 amd64 Oracle Instant Client Light package
oracle-instantclient12.2-devel 12.2.0.1.0-2 amd64 Development headers for Instant Client.
oracle-instantclient12.2-sqlplus 12.2.0.1.0-2 amd64 SQL*Plus for Instant Client.
```

Copied the same tnsnames, sqlnet and listener files, added same environment variables.

But. From the old machine the actual connection to the database in sqlplus takes about 0.5sec:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Apr 16 16:17:13 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
[0,5sec]
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

And from the new one there is a pause of about 1 minute before displaying "Connected".

*After* connection is established, both sessions appear blazing fast when doing the queries.

I looked at the initial ideas regarding network and DNS resolution, but both machines are the same in this respect.

Is there anything Oracle serverside that could account for this?